# How to match a unique patter using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, posix

I have a text file called 'file.txt' with the content like,

```
test:one
test_test:two
test_test_test:three
```

If the pattern is `test`, then the expected output should be `one` and similarly for the other two lines.

This is what I have tried.

`pattern=test && awk '{split($0,i,":"); if (i[1] ~ /'"$pattern"'$/) print i[2]}'`

This command gives the output like,

```
one
two
three
```

and `pattern=test_test && awk '{split($0,i,":"); if (i[1] ~ /'"$pattern"'$/) print i[2]}'`

```
two
three
```

How can I match the unique pattern being "test" for "test" and not for "**test**_test" and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I match the unique pattern being `test` for `test` and not for `test_test` and so on.

Don't use a regex for comparing the value, just use equality:

```bash
awk -F: -v pat='test' '$1 == pat {print $2}' file
one

awk -F: -v pat='test_test' '$1 == pat {print $2}' file
two
```

If you really want to use regex, then use it like this with anchors:

```bash
awk -F: -v pat='test' '$1 ~ "^" pat "$" {print $2}' file

one
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a regex, you can create it dynamically with `pattern` and optionally repeating `_` followed by pattern until matching a `:`

If it matches the start of the string, then you can print the second field.

```
awk -v pattern='test' -F: '
$0 ~ "^"pattern"(_"pattern")*:" {
    print $2
}
' file
```

Output

```
one
two
three
```

Or if only matching the part before the first underscore is also ok, then splitting field 1 on `_` and printing field 2:

```
awk -v pattern='test' -F: ' {
  split($1, a, "_")
  if(a[1] == pattern) print $2
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` with word boundaries

```
$ sed -n '/\<test\>/s/[^:]*://p' input_file
one
```